# Passing variables to CloudFunction in ParseSwift correctly

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I've been trying to make my static CloudCode function dynamic by passing data when calling the function.

I've been using the template from the ParseSwift Playground to create a CloudCode struct that takes variables, and then run my function.

On the server, I want to assign the passed data to a Push Notification payload. To access the passed data from the CloudFunction, I followed the ParseServer documentation, which had the examples only for the old Parse SDK.

When I run my Cloud function it gets called, but the server sends back an error 141, telling me that 'request' is not defined.

I simply want to pass String data to modify the text in a Push Notification that is sent via CloudCode.

Here is my CloudFunction:

```
struct CloudFunction: ParseCloud {

    //: Return type of your Cloud Function
    typealias ReturnType = String

    //: These are required by `ParseCloud`
    var functionJobName: String

    //: If your cloud function takes arguments, they can be passed by creating properties:
    //var argument1: [String: Int] = ["test": 5]
    var test1: [String: String]
    var test2: [String: String]
}
```

When calling the CloudFunction, I do this:

```
let data1 = ["test1": "abc"]
let data2 = ["test2": "def"]
let pushTest = CloudFunction(functionJobName: "pushsample", test1: data1, test2: data2)
                    
pushTest.runFunction { result in
   switch result {
   case .success(let response):
      print("Response from cloud function: \(response)")
   case .failure(let error):
      assertionFailure("Error calling cloud function: \(error)")
   }
}
```

And the CloudCode function is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('pushsample', async () => {
       
       var data1 = request.params.test1; 
       var data2 = request.params.test2;
       
       Parse.Push.send({
         channels: ["testChannel"],
            data: {
                alert: data1,
                title: data2,
            }
        }, { useMasterKey: true });
      
      return 'pushsample called successfully';
});
```

I tried passing different parameters (String instead of [String: String] for instance), but that didn't work either

How do I define `request` inside the CloudCode function, or how do I correctly pass data to the server via a CloudFunction in ParseSwift?

I'm using ParseServer 4.2.0. and ParseSwift 2.5.1 - thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem looks to be in your cloud code function. The signature must be something like this: `Parse.Cloud.define('pushsample', async (request) => {`

Answer (score 0):

As Davi suggested, adding `request` allowed me to access my passed data.

The Swift Playground file uses a Dictionary as an example argument for the Cloud Code function. Since this adds an additional step of accessing your data within the CloudCode function via the defined key-value pair, I simplified it to simple String values passed into the function. This also works.

Here are the parts of the code that I changed, for everyone interested:

CloudCode:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('pushsample', async (request) => {
       
       var data1 = request.params.test1; 
       var data2 = request.params.test2;
       
       Parse.Push.send({
         channels: ["testChannel"],
            data: {
                alert: data1,
                title: data2,
            }
        }, { useMasterKey: true });
      
      return 'pushsample called successfully';
});
```

CloudFunction:

```
struct CloudFunction: ParseCloud {

    typealias ReturnType = String

    var functionJobName: String

    var test1: String
    var test2: String
}
```

Calling the CloudFunction:

```
let pushTest = CloudFunction(functionJobName: "pushsample", test1: "data1", test2: "data2")
pushTest.runFunction { result in
   switch result {
   case .success(let response):
      print("Response from cloud function: \(response)")
   case .failure(let error):
      assertionFailure("Error calling cloud function: \(error)")
   }
}
```

Note: In my case, the order of assigning `alert` before `title` inside the CloudCode definition on the server is important to make sure the push notification is displayed correctly. Assigning `title` before `alert` will cause the push notification to only show your app name with any `alert` message defined below it.